# Why does my objects look different when I enter the game engine?

Tags: game-engine

Normal [image]

In game engine[image]

What is wrong and how can I fix this ?

Comment: My guess is your normals are inverted and the game engine does back face culling where the 3d viewport doesn't. Can you check that the normals are facing outward?